# Distributed KD-tree

Tags: algorithm, distributed, distributed-computing, kdtree

My friend and I are working on a project for distributed KD-tree with applications to location-aware services in mind.

Can anyone point us to papers related to this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[scholar.google.com](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=distributed+KD-tree&hl=en&btnG=Search&as_sdt=400000001&as_sdtp=on) is your friend, 7th link down or so to get started. [citeseer.org](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/) is another great resource for finding CS papers.